# Check if document exists before creating a new one in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am using Mongoose and NodeJS. I want to create a document, in some collection only if document in another collection exists, without making two queries to the database.

For an example lets say we have a collections of locations and apartments. Location _id is passed on the creation of a new apartment and the apartment stores it. So I want to create a document for new apartment only if location with such an _id exists.
I know that I can check for a location, using query, and then to create apartment only if the query return a result, but by this way I'am making two queries to the DB and the code becomes hard to mange.

I'am asking if there is a better way to this by telling MongoDB to do this check for me.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make two queries.

There's no such thing as referential integrity in mongodb